# Find a property (which is stored as a string in a variable) in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects which store the data of different 'pupils'.

```
var pupils = [
{
    id: 0,
    name: 'will'
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'megan'
}
];
```

I want to create a function called 'findPupil' which takes three parameters: the property you know, the value you know it to be and the property you want to find.

Say you know that the pupil you are looking for has an id of 1 but you don't know their name. In this case, you would call the function like this:

```
var name = findPupil('id', 1, 'name'); // should now store 'Megan' as a string
```

Here is the function I have written:

```
function findPupil(property, value, find) {
pupils.forEach(function(pupil) {
    if(pupils[pupil][`${property}`] === value) {
      return pupils[pupil][`${find}`];
    }
  });
}
```

Calling this function returns the following:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

How do I make this function work?

Comment: What is `array1`

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy&paste mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that.

```js
var pupils = [{id: 0, name: 'will'},{id: 1,name: 'megan'}];

function getByPropertyAndValue(knownProp, knownValue, desiredProperty) {
  let pupil = pupils.find(p => p[knownProp] === knownValue); //Find pupil by property and value
  return pupil && pupil[desiredProperty]; //Return the value, or undefined if not found
}

console.log(getByPropertyAndValue("id", 1, "name"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find an object with the property you know, or a default if an object is not found. Extract the `find` property from the object:

```js
const pupils = [{"id":0,"name":"will"},{"id":1,"name":"megan"}];

const findPupil = (property, value, find) =>
  (pupils.find(o => o[property] === value) || {})[find];

const name = findPupil('id', 1, 'name');

console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is correct except for the part of your `if` statement. Please find working example -

```js
var pupils = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'will'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'megan'
  }
];

function findPupil(property, value, find) {
  let result
  pupils.forEach(function(pupil) {
    if (pupil[property] === value) {
      result = pupil[find];
    }
  });
  return result
}

var name = findPupil('id', 1, 'name');

console.log(name)
```

Comment: `\`${property}\`` template literal isn't required here since `property` and `find` are already strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pupils = [
    { id: 0, name: 'will' },
    { id: 1, name: 'megan' }
];

function findPupil(property, value, find) {
    var find_value = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < pupils.length; i++) {
        if (find_value == '') {
            Object.keys(pupils[i]).forEach(function (key) {
                if (key == property && pupils[i][key] == value) {
                    find_value = pupils[i][find];
                }
            });
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(find_value);
    return find_value;
}

var name = findPupil('id', 1, 'name');
```